# I <3 conditionals

Tags: code-golf, string, parsing

You end up having a lot of very long, boring-looking conditionals in your code:

```py
if flag == 1:

while have != needed:

if type == 7:
```

These can be transformed into their much more lovable `<3` conditionals counterparts:

```py
if abs(flag - 1) + 2 <3:

while 3 - abs(have - needed) <3:

if 2 + abs(type - 7) <3:
```

#### Task

Your task is to take a conditional and make it in terms of `<3`. The only spacing that matters is that there is none between `<` and `3`.

Conditionals will be two expressions seperated by either `==`, `!=`, `>`, `<`, `>=` or `<=`.
Expressions will only contain addition, subtraction, unary negation (`-something`), where there is one `+` or `-` before each variables or numbers (except the first which has nothing or `-` before it).
Numbers will be `[0-9]+`, and variables will be `[a-z]+`. If the answer needs to use `|x|` (The absolute value of `x`), use the `abs()` function. You may assume that all variables are integers, and all number constants in the input are < 1000.

The output does *not* need to be in it's simplest form. It does need to be a conditional like above, meaning that it is two expressions only, seperated by one conditional sign, but it can also use the `abs` function, enclosing a valid expression, and then it acts like a variable, in terms of validity.

If the input does not have an output for any value of a variable, output a condition that is always false, but still in terms of `<3`.

Part of the challenge is figuring out how to do it, but here are the steps for the `have != needed` above:

```py
have != needed
have - needed != 0
abs(have - needed) > 0
-abs(have - needed) < 0
3 - abs(have - needed) <3
```

#### Scoring

This is code-golf, so the shortest valid code, in bytes, wins.

#### Test cases

(Note, these outputs aren't the only outputs, but I tried to simplify them.)

```py
flag == 1
abs(flag - 1) + 2 <3

have != needed
3 - abs(have - needed) <3

type == 7
2 + abs(type - 7) <3

x > y
3 - x + y <3

x + 5 < -y
x + 8 + y <3

x + 6 <= y
x + 8 - y <3

-x >= y + 3
x + y + 5 <3

x < x
3 <3
# Unsimplified; both would be valid outputs.
x - x + 3 <3
```

Comment: Is there always exactly one space between input tokens?

Comment: @Doorknob No. There will be 0 or 1 spaces.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 95 bytes

```
<=
<1+
>=
>-1+
(.*)(.=)(.*)
$2abs($1-($3))
==
2+
!=
3-
(.*)>(.*)
$2<$1
(.*)<(.*)
$1-($2)+3
$
<3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcrLCoAgEEbh/f8UBrNwEgV1O@O7GFQE0aJ6f7uuDge@fTyXrbYmCokORVH8XRt6tkH5KSjV4bAUvaXMDFUkh06R/evKj4Ti@/L9wxO7DILk1qa1zkbVxAs)

A rather naïve solution, but I haven't been able to find any improvements.

This is just a series of replacements:

```
<=
<1+
>=
>-1+
```

Get rid of "or equal to" comparisons by replacing `x <= y` with `x < 1 + y`, and `x >= y` with `x > -1 + y`.

```
(.*)(.=)(.*)
$2abs($1-($3))
```

Replace `x == y` with `==abs(x - y)`, and `x != y` with `!=abs(x - y)`.

```
==
2+
!=
3-
```

Replace `==` with `2+` and `!=` with `3-`, so that the overall replacements become `x == y` → `2 + abs(x - y)` and `x != y` → `3 - abs(x - y)`.

```
(.*)>(.*)
$2<$1
```

Normalize the direction of the remaining inequalities, replacing `x > y` with `y < x`.

```
(.*)<(.*)
$1-($2)+3
```

Replace `x < y` with `x - y + 3`.

```
$
<3
```

Append a heart to the end of the string.